# JWT authorization token is generated at the client side but it is not working at the API

Tags: rest, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt, authorization

i have tried implementing the **jwt authentication**, as the token is being generated correctly at the client side but the **Web API** is not authenticating the request from the client side, i have provided the code that i have used and i am implementing this in **asp.net core 1.1.**
i have made sure that the token is generating the valid information using **JWT.io** and everything is fine.

**this is code at the Web API which will verify the incoming token from another server**

```
        app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate=true,
            IncludeErrorDetails=true,               
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidAudience = "exampleissuer",
                ValidIssuer = "exampleaudience",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superkey_ValueforSigningTheJSONWebTokenJWT"))
            }
        });
```

**this is code in the application where the token is generated and sent through the request.**

```
var signinKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
```

Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superkey_ValueforSigningTheJSONWebTokenJWT"));

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: "exampleissuer",
    audience: "exampleaudience",
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(signinKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)
);

var AuthenticationToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            //                
_restClient.Authenticator = new JwtAuthenticator(AuthenticationToken);

req.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", string.Format("Bearer {0}", AuthenticationToken));

_restClient.Authenticator.Authenticate(_restClient, req);
            //
```

**could someone help me to authenticate the token in web api.**

Comment: @timbiegeleisen, i have made the changes, so as you can understand and help me accomplish this.